# How can I find out, which buttons are removed by default from the CKEditor npm Standard Edition v4?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In a previous question

[How to understand CKEditor4's "justify" option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64350734/how-to-understand-ckeditor4s-justify-option)

I learned that the CDN standard Version of CKEditor v4 removes some buttons. By trial-and-error I found out that superscript and subscript seem to be 2 of them.

I also know that "removebuttons": "" will undo any presets and therefore enable superscript and subscript.

But how/where can I find out, which buttons exactly are hidden by default by that very npm preset?

If I would just like to activate "superscript", for example, but keep the other buttons hidden, I can't just use "removebuttons":"". Instead, I have to add the current list of "removebuttons", just without superscript. Right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime I am just blocked.. it is easy to find out by doing a simple "console.log(CKEDITOR)" of course. Then, the answer as to which buttons are hidden by default can be found in the "CKEDITOR.instances[instance].config.removeButtons". It is "Underline,Subscript,Superscript".